# Document.onclick is not firing on fitbit studio

Tags: javascript, fitbit

My document.onclick is not firing on fitbit studio. Here is my code:

```
import document from "document";
var ctally = 0;
const updateTally = () => {
    var fNum;
    if (ctally <= -1) {
        ctally = 0;
        fNum = "000";
    } else if (ctally < 999) {
        fNum = ("00" + ctally).slice(-3).toString();
    } else {
        fNum = ctally.toString();
    }
    document.getElementById("tally").textContent = fNum;
};
// other code... including a document.onkeypress working fine
document.onclick = () => {
    console.log("Hi!");
    ctally++;
    updateTally();
};
```

I don't know what I did wrong. No errors are produced in either log. Building for Fitbit Versa if it makes a difference. Hi! is not being logged to the console (that is how I knew it was not firing).

Comment: If you put the `onclick` before the other code with the `onkeypress` does it work? If so it might be an issue with your other code.

Comment: @Andy no and my other code is working fine when flipped over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.onclick` is not supported on the device.

Instead, you could create a new element `<rect width="100%" height="100%" opacity="0" id="tap-target" pointer-events="all"/>` at then end of your GUI file that transparently covers the entire screen, then add the `onclick` handler to it (`document.getElementById('tap-target').onclick = ...`. This only works in the case where you have no other touch controls on the screen, as this rect will capture all touch events.